# Is there a CSV Import function in either version of ag-grid?

Tags: csv, import, ag-grid

I'm trying to understand the import/export API options available with ag-grid. In the community edition, I've found the CSV Export grid API function, which works fine, but I can't find a corresponding Import function.  Is there one?  If not, why not?  Am I missing something obvious perhaps?

I'm not interested in the Enterprise edition at this time, unless there's a CSV importer function hiding in there?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, as far as I know.

The reason is that the grid is meant to be a visual component that displays data that you provide to it in the form of an array of objects.

If you want to "import" data into the grid, you're probably going to have to write code to read the data from wherever you want to import it from, and provide it to the grid via it's "rowData" binding, and also set up the column definitions to match the columns in the data.

Comment: Thank you @GreyBeardedGeek. I've whipped up the code you suggested, and it works fine.  But I do find it odd they offer one but not the other.